# How do the Marvel One-Shots fit into the MCU timeline?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, timeline, marvel-one-shots

There are several Marvel One-Shots, short films that were released as extras on Blu-Ray releases of certain movies. The full list is:

- *The Consultant* (September 13, 2011) | *Thor*
- *A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to Thor's Hammer* (October 25, 2011) | *Captain America: The First Avenger*
- *Item 47* (September 25, 2012) | *The Avengers*
- *Agent Carter*, (September 3, 2013) | *Iron Man 3*
- *All Hail the King* (February 4, 2014) | *Thor: The Dark World*

How do these fit into the current Marvel timeline? This includes all currently released Marvel Cinematic Universe titles.

Comment: I double checked, these are all included in the linked  question.